# "Checkbord-like" binary selection

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array

```
test = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

for which I need a "checkboard" like selector. Basically, I want to select odd elements in the first row, even elements in the second row, odd elements in the third row etc..

In this case (because the row numbers are odd) I can get that via

```
test.flatten()[::2]
Out[22]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24])
```

which is exactly "every other element" in both dimensions. But if we try that with

```
test2 = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))
test2
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
test2.flatten()[::2]
Out[27]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14])
```

unsurprisingly, it doesn't work out.

What's a *general* way of generating the type of selection that I want, no matter the shape of the (2d) matrix? Is it easily (or even possible) to extend to 3d matrices?

**I do prefer efficient (vectorized or cython-based) approaches.**

---

Bonus: **3D**:

```
test3 = np.arange(25*3).reshape((3, 5, 5))
Out[30]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],
       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],
       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]]])
```

Here it's not about odd and even *rows*, but rather about neighboring elements. **No two neighboring elements** should have the same color (be part of the same bool selector).

That is, if we select `test3[0, ...].flatten()[::2]` we get `[0, ... 24]`. The neighboring element of `0` in the first dimension is `25`, so we don't want that. The expected output is

```
np.hstack((test3[0, ...].flatten()[::2], test3[1, ...].flatten()[1::2], test3[2, ...].flatten()[::2], ))
Out[42]: 
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32,
       34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46])
```

Comment: @Divakar does this clarify the 3D case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized solution -

```
def checker_select(a):
    m,n = a.shape[-2:]
    i,j = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
    mask = (i+j)%2==0
    return a.reshape(-1,m,n)[:,mask].ravel()
```

Probably a faster one with `array-initialization` -

```
def checker_select_v2(a):
    m,n = a.shape[-2:]
    mask = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=bool)
    mask[::2,::2] = 1
    mask[1::2,1::2] = 1
    return a.reshape(-1,m,n)[:,mask].ravel()
```

Sample run for `2D` -

```
In [117]: a
Out[117]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [118]: checker_select(a)
Out[118]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24])
```

Sample run for `3D` -

```
In [144]: a
Out[144]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
        [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
        [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
        [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
        [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24]],

       [[ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
        [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34],
        [ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
        [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44],
        [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49]],

        ....

In [145]: checker_select(a)
Out[145]: 
array([  0,   2,   4,   6,   8,  10,  12,  14,  16,  18,  20,  22,  24,
        25,  27,  29,  31,  33,  35,  37,  39,  41,  43,  45,  47,  49,
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in plain old python

```
mat = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))

result = []
for row in range(len(mat)):
    for col in range(len(mat[row])):
        if row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 == 0:
            result.append(mat[row][col])
        elif row % 2 == 1 and col % 2 == 1:
            result.append(mat[row][col])

print(result)
```

### Output

```
[0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 15]
```

If you are looking for a more pythonic way.

```
n = 6
m = 4
mat = np.arange(n * m).reshape((n, m))

flat = mat.flatten()
result = [flat[i] for i in range(len(flat)) if i // m % 2 == i % m % 2]
print(result)
```

### Output

```
[0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18, 21, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using basic lists and plain python.

```
matrix = [
    [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
    [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14, 15]
]

result = (row[i % 2::2] for i, row in enumerate(matrix))

flattened_result = [cell for filtered_row in result for cell in filtered_row]

print(flattened_result)
```

Comment: I think the output will be as a list of lists and not a single one

Comment: Yep. Forgot to flatten it. Thanks for the call out!